# Functional Dependencies

Tags: sql, database

I need a bit of help with understanding the functional dependencies. I have an example here:

```
A B C D E
--
1 0 1 7 2
1 0 4 3 5
1 0 1 7 5
1 0 4 3 2
```

What functional dependencies do we have here?
Which of them are multivalued?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency

Comment: It looks like you're missing the left most column.  Should it say 
A 1 0 1 7 2, 
B 1 0 4 3 5, C 1 0 1 7 5, D 1 0 4 3 2?

Comment: dev_feed, I didn't missed anything. I see that someone just helped me with the formating. I guess now is easier to understand what I have there. @Ghost, thank you. I already read the theory and I have the background but I just can't undestand how to apply it in examples like this.

Answer (score 2):

A functional dependency answers the question, "Given one value for *this* set of columns, do I know one and only one value for *that* set of columns?"

So, for example, given one value for column A, do I know one and only one value for column B? Yes. So column A determines column B, or in common notation, A->B.

Given one value for column A, do I know one and only one value for column C? No.

To determine all the functional dependencies, you have to answer the question for every combination of columns. Textbooks usually give at least one pencil-and-paper algorithm, and they often include shortcuts.

Comment: I undestand. C -> D  sould be another functional dependency. Now, please give me one more example of multivalued functional dependency. Thank you :)